# Using Xlwt / Xlutils to paste data into excel from Microsoft Clipboard

Tags: python, xlwt

Using the xlwt module in python for windows, I would like to copy data to microsoft's clipboard, then write the data into excel directly. Does anyone know the function for this?

I'm trying to copy paste data from a program and send clipboard's contents into excel in a listing manner where each subsequent paste of data selects the next new empty cell underneath the previous pasted contents.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that with anything in the xl* packages.  They're tools for manipulating Excel *files*, not interfacing with Microsoft Excel.

Comment: What about a notepad file? Same idea where you paste data directly into the file, then each subsequent paste pastes directly underneath the last. Is that possible?